# How to pass insecure registry as args in pipeline using DIND image

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, docker-in-docker

can someone please let me know on how to pass insecure registry as an argument when using DIND image as runtime container.
Please find the below sample script which i had been using as docker run time agent.
'''

```
pipeline {
       agent {label 'jenkins-docker-slave'}
              stages{             
                  stage('maven version'){ 
                         agent {docker { image 'maven:latest'}}                                                         
                     steps{
                        script{                              
                          sh "mvn --version"
                               }           
                          
                         }
                   }
                  stage('docker build'){                          
                         agent {
                                   docker { 
                                           image 'docker:dind'
                                           args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'                                           
                                           
                            }
                         }
                     steps{                            
                        script{  
      
                          sh 'docker version'  
                            }
                         }
                    }
 }
}
```

'''

Docker version works fine but my motive is to set insecure registry as below during the runtime so that i can use docker login and docker push commands successfully.

```
{
  "insecure-registries": [
    "ec2-52-39-183-6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8123"
  ]
}
```

I want to make the above condition work during the runtime. Can someone please advise on how this can be achived with DIND?

Comment: Can you use [AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html) to get a valid TLS certificate for the registry, so you don't need this option?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my query on my own. Below is the solution:

```
sh 'docker exec --tty $(docker ps -ql) sh -c "mkdir -p /etc/docker"' 
sh 'docker exec --tty $(docker ps -ql) sh -c "mkdir -p /root/.docker"'
sh '''
    docker exec --tty $(docker ps -ql) sh -c "cat <<EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
    {
           "insecure-registries": [
              "ec2-52-36-87-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8123"
                                      ]
     }"
'''
```

But the only problem is , the above used port 8123 for the docker repository connector is not opened due to which getting the below error.

> Error response from daemon

Is there any way to open ports within docker container to get this worked?